# Silicon wafer crystal orientation

Tags: crystal, silicon

I'm confused about how [110] direction is determined for (100), (110) or (111) wafers. I found a book chapter which just confused me even more. From the image below, I understand how [110] is determined on the (110) wafer but not the other two.
I'm also having a hard time understanding what different planes would look like on the (111) and (110) wafer. I would appreciate a resource for silicon wafers specifically (not necessarily crystallography).
Here are things I'm not understanding.

1. How is the [110] direction determined and why is it different for each of the three wafers below? For the (110) wafer [110] is between x and y axis which makes sense. But for (100) it seems to go from z to y and for (111) it's between x and z. From my understanding [110] intercepts x and y axis at 1 and doesn't intercept z axis but that doesn't seem to be the case for (100) and (111) wafers.
2. Does the definition of x,y and z axis change when we're talking about (100), (111) or (110) wafers? I know that whichever wafer it is, that direction will be pointing out from the wafer surface but when I draw planes with respect to [110] and [111] (for (111) wafer), I don't know where the (100) plane should be. (110) plane would be perpendicular to the [110] direction and would be normal to the surface and (111) would be 35° from it. I can't find a drawing for it which makes me think we don't need to show the (100) plane? But if not then what if I need to align my mask to (100) plane on (111) wafer?
3. How would I define higher miller index planes on the 3 wafers? For example I need to align my mask to (122) or (411) plane, how would I start with it? I understand that this might become clear once I learn about the primary planes on the wafers.

[image]

Comment: Saying that you are confused is unhelpful. Asking for resources is probably off-topic. Why are you confused?

Comment: You're right I'll edit to add my confusion